# Can the main function be declared before is defined?

Tags: c, function, declaration, program-entry-point, function-definition

I know that the main function is just a "special" function, but can it be declared and then defined like any other function or not?

This is also correct :

```
int main(void);

int main(void) {

}
```

or just this is correct :

```
int main(void) {

}
```

?

P.S. I know that when a function is defined is automatically declared, but I didn't know how to formulate this question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to create a declaration for the `main` function (provided it matches the definition).

It just won't be of any use because nothing else in your program calls `main`, or at least it shouldn't.